# Can I timestamp a specific field in a rails db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a checkbox that users tick to provide consent. When this form is posted the Users table is updated with a field that confirms consent is provided. However I also want record the date/time that consent was provided. To this end I was hoping to have a 'user_consent' field that would store 'yes' and a user_consent_agreed' field that would store the date/time that the user_consent field was updated.

I know I can add timestamps to a table on creation but this will change when any attribute is updated, I need to record time/date in its own field when the consent attribute changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would just have one column in the table `consented_at`, which is of type `DateTime`. When they consent, you update that column:

`user.update_column :consented_at, DateTime.now`

I used `consented_at` to keep it inline with `created_at` and `updated_at`

This way, you can tell if a person has consented or not and when they consented (if they did).

```
if user.consented_at?
  # consented and you have the time in consented_at
else
  # never consented
end
```

No real need to have a `boolean` column and a time since checking the time column will return true or false anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, add a `consented_at` column to hold the timestamp.

To automatically update this column when the value of `consented` changes, add a `before_save` callback to your model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_save do
    self.consented_at = Time.zone.now if consented_changed?
  end

end
```

Note that this will set `consented_at` on any change to `consented`, even setting it to false. If that's not what you want, you can adjust the code inside the callback as desired.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html for more on model callbacks. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html for more on how to detect changes.